# Margin doesn't get applied to a footer

Tags: html, css, margin

Here is my website so you can see the problem: [webpage](http://freshbeer.lv/final/index.php)

The problem is that my `.footer`
Has a `margin: 50px 0 50px 0;` , but for some reason it doesn't appear to have that 50px margin from top. I don't understand what is causing the problem.

Here is full css of footer section (`.dashed-footer` is basically inner section of the footer  with that dashed border.)

**CSS**

```
.footer {
    margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
    background-color: #1d130e;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid #0d0907;
    border-bottom: 1px soid #0d0907;
    clear: both;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -1px #181513;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -1px #181513;
}

.dashed-footer {
    height: 37px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 38px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #613e27 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #613e27 !important;
    color: #e6d7bb;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

Comment: ups, sorry had a typo, fixed it

Comment: So, the problem is the footer touches #trio-3?

Comment: @11684 yes, i don't know why that is...

Comment: I discovered something very strange, it doesn't move if you increment that value until you enter 500px, and then it jumps down! But I think I got the answer, give me a minute!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the `section.content` is the answer. It is because the elements inside it are floated which takes them out of the normal flow of the document.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the margin is applied, 50px down from `<section id="content">`, but the trio is for some reason placed outside that section, and pushing the footer down! If you choose 'inspect element' and mouse-over `<section id="content">` you can see it stops at the downside of the slides, and the trio is below there. I think the solution is to do `margin: [height of trio plus margins, borders, etc] + 50px 0 50px 0;`

Comment: What if the height is dynamic?

Comment: Use calc(). Not very well supported, but as a fallback... @PeeHaa

Comment: In IE to be substituted by expression().

Comment: Cool didn't know about `calc()`. Feels like something one should avoid though for this specific issue. Still may be useful for other things though. Thanks!